# Java star pattern program not sending expected output

Tags: java

Working on a java program that should take as input an even number and the print out a star pattern of asterisk symbols with spaces. I have it working with an input of 6, but no higher and have no clue why.

My Code:

```
package starpattern;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StarPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int rows, cols;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many columns? ");
        cols = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (cols%2 == 0)
        {
            int col2 = cols;
            int spaces = (cols/2 - 1);
            int ASTS = 2;
                        int test = (col2/2);
                        while (cols > (col2/2))
            {
                for (int x = spaces; x > 0; x--)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int y = ASTS; y > 0; y--)
                    {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                for (int z = spaces; z > 0; z --)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                cols--;
                ASTS +=2;
                spaces--;
            }
                        spaces = (cols/2 - 1);
            while (cols > 0)
            {

                if (test != (col2/2))
                                {
                                    for (int x = spaces; x < (cols/2); x++)
                                    {
                                            System.out.print(" ");
                                    }
                                    spaces -=2;

                                }



                                for (int a = ASTS-2; a > 0; a--)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");

                }
                                test++;
                                System.out.println();
                                cols--;
                ASTS -= 2;


            }
                }
    }
}
```

Each step up (10, 12,...) has some form of the same issue. Is there a way I can fix this on the bottom half (Starting at "while cols>0") So that it gives the proper output of spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find what you actually doing in your code, but it is a bit overkill :). Maybe your reversed method is wrong at all and it is hardcoded to work only for number 6.

However I appreciate your effort and I can show you, how to write it better. This is a fully working code in Java :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many rows? ");
    int rows = keyboard.nextInt();

    triangle(rows);
    triangleReversed(rows);
}

private static void triangle(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i * 2 + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

private static void triangleReversed(int n) {
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i * 2 + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

With this sample output :

```
How many rows? 12
           *
          ***
         *****
        *******
       *********
      ***********
     *************
    ***************
   *****************
  *******************
 *********************
***********************
***********************
 *********************
  *******************
   *****************
    ***************
     *************
      ***********
       *********
        *******
         *****
          ***
           *
```

Note that it is good to separate program into methods for better readability. Also note that method triangle and triangleReversed is almost identical, it differs only on theirs first row.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**------Smart Coding------Good Coder**

```
**Very Simplest Way To create Paramid use only three loops**
```

D:\Java>java ParamidExample
Enter a number
5

```
      *
    * * *
  * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

---

```
* * * * * * *
  * * * * *
    * * *
      *

import java.util.*;
public class ParamidExample
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int no=sc.nextInt();

        int count=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=2*no-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=count;j<=no;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("  "); 
            }
            for(int k=1;k<=count*2-1;k++)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
        if(i<no)
            count++;
        else
            count--;
                System.out.println(""); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Very Simplest Way To create Paramid use only three loops**

Comment: Using else Part Draw   Reverse Trangle   No Need To create again three loops........... Here You Save three loops